# Kivy countdown Label

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to perform a countdown with the Label.

By updating the label's text I believe it is possible.

My intention is to start the countdown after the user presses the start button

**But it's not working!!!**

Here is my code

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
import time


class WelcomeScreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start = Button(text="Start Game", pos=(350, 250))
        self.add_widget(self.start)
        self.count = Label(text="", pos=(350, 250),font_size=90)
        self.start.bind(on_press=self.start_game)

    def start_game(self, obj):
        num = 0
        self.remove_widget(self.start)
        self.add_widget(self.count)
        for i in range(1, 4):
            num += 1
            self.count.text = str(num)
            time.sleep(1)



class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return WelcomeScreen()

TestApp().run()
```

I know this is a stupid problem but I cant't really figure it out how to solve it.
Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short anwser: Use the Clock

```
def start_game(self, obj):
    num = 0
    self.remove_widget(self.start)
    self.add_widget(self.count)
    def count_it(num):
        if num == 4: 
            return
        num += 1
        self.count.text = str(num)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: count_it(num), 1)

    Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: count_it(0), 0)
```

Longer:
When you are running python code the kivy event loop is waiting so nothing gets update in the screen, when you do time.sleep you stall the process...

The Clock schedule_* methods allow you to set callbacks while letting the event loop run when you are idle

You can also use a thread and call Clock.schedule_once just for the updates but for your use case the code above is simpler